# How to parse one block of JSON data instead of the entire JSON sequence

Tags: json, swift, decodable

Below is the code that am using to parse a JSON api. The code works and i am able to parse all the JSON values into the struct below but i would like to know how to parse only the first block(?)/ array and store them in the struct so that i can perform operations on them.

```
     let jsonUrlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&apikey=demo"

        let urlObj = URL(string: jsonUrlString)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                print(forex.timeSeriesFX5Min)
            } catch {

                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()
    }
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let timeSeriesFX5Min: [String:Forex]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesFX5Min = "Time Series FX (5min)"
    }
}


    // MARK: - TimeSeriesFX5Min
    struct Forex: Codable {
        let the1Open, the2High, the3Low, the4Close: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case the1Open = "1. open"
            case the2High = "2. high"
            case the3Low = "3. low"
            case the4Close = "4. close"
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does `first block` mean?

Comment: When you open the JSON api via the url you get a list of values:
"Time Series FX (5min)": {
        "2019-06-19 14:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.1213",
            "2. high": "1.1213",
            "3. low": "1.1210",
            "4. close": "1.1212"
        },
Am trying to capture that first set of values instead of all of them and then store those first block of values so that they can be used to perform operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to do this, the first requires a change to the Root struct where we need to use the Meta Data part of the message

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let metaData: [String: String]
    let timeSeriesFX5Min: [String:Forex]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesFX5Min = "Time Series FX (5min)"
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
    }
}
```

Then we pick up the item labeled "Last Refresed" and use the value to look up the latest price entry in the time series dictionary

```
do {
    let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(forex.metaData)
    if let latestTime = forex.metaData["4. Last Refreshed"], let latestForex = forex.timeSeriesFX5Min[latestTime] {
        print(latestForex)
    }        
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that the timestamps are given in such a format that they can be properly sorted so instead of using meta data we sort the keys and pick the last item

```
if let latestTime = forex.timeSeriesFX5Min.keys.sorted().last, let latestForex = forex.timeSeriesFX5Min[latestTime] {
     print(latestForex)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind solution one. It worked, thank you but i would like to understand as to why you chose that method for future purposes.

Comment: First of all I didn't choose one over the other, I just happened to present them in that order. The first solution has the advantage that it gives a clear reference for what the last record is but will require a little more code and depends on the metadata structure doesn't change.  The second one is simpler but might be a tad slower due to the sorting if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request you probably will notify who call your method with the request value by callback right ?
So you will create a new instance of your object or array object and fill with the result.

If you will create in this structure you just gonna take your arrayObject and use .first and do your logic following this...

Example:

```
var newRoot: [Root] = [] 
func loadRoot() {
    Service().makeRequest() { (result, error) int
         newRoot = result.results
         print(newRoot.first)
    }
}
```

The function "makeRequest()" will call the method that you wrote.

```
let jsonUrlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&apikey=demo"

    let urlObj = URL(string: jsonUrlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            print(forex.timeSeriesFX5Min)
        } catch {

            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: And this function would parse only the first block of values and then store them, in the struct that was created?