# How to decode JSON that contains a date information?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, structure

I have JSON structure as:

```
"symbol": "SNAP",

"stock_exchange_short": "NYSE",
"timezone_name": "America/New_York",
"intraday": {

    "2019-12-20 15:59:00": {
        "open": "15.55",
        "close": "15.55",
        "high": "15.55",
        "low": "15.52",
        "volume": "670218"
    },
    "2019-12-20 15:58:00": {
        "open": "15.55",
        "close": "15.55",
        "high": "15.55",
        "low": "15.54",
        "volume": "284225"
    },
   ...
}
```

Any ideas how to implement the date informations
I tried to parse it like this:

```
public struct WorldTradingIntradayData: Decodable {
    let symbol : String
    let stock_exchange_short : String
    let timezone_name : String
    let intraday : Intraday?
 }
public struct Intraday: Decodable {
    let dateTime: WorldTradingIntradayDetails

 public struct WorldTradingIntradayDetails: Decodable {
     let open : String
     let close : String
     let high : String
     let low : String
     let volume : String
    }
```

But it's not working as its supposed to.
Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: in your decode part implement `do/catch` to help you figure the error

Comment: `intraday` should be Array instead of an object!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse one block of JSON data instead of the entire JSON sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669677/how-to-parse-one-block-of-json-data-instead-of-the-entire-json-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
let intraday : Intraday?
```

with

```
let intraday : [String:WorldTradingIntradayDetails]
```

And completely get rid of `public struct Intraday: Decodable {`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be considered just as string, then if you want to convert it into a date, you will need to change the `T` for the space to create a `dateFormatter`:

```
struct WorldTradingIntradayData: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let stockExchangeShort: String
    let timezoneName: String
    let intraday: [String: Intraday]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol
        case stockExchangeShort = "stock_exchange_short"
        case timezoneName = "timezone_name"
        case intraday
    }
}

struct Intraday: Decodable {
    let intradayOpen: String
    let close: String
    let high: String 
    let low: String
    let volume: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case intradayOpen = "open"
        case close
        case high
        case low 
        case volume
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its too late to answer but just added the full code if some one still needs it.

```
  struct WorldTradingIntradayData: Codable {
    let symbol: String
    let stock_exchange_short: String
    let timezone_name: String
    let intraday: [String: DataModel]
  }

  struct DataModel: Codable {
    let open: String
    let close: String
    let high: String
    let low: String
    let volume: String
  }

  let resultsJson = """
{
  "symbol": "SNAP",

  "stock_exchange_short": "NYSE",
  "timezone_name": "America/New_York",
  "intraday": {

    "2019-12-20 15:59:00": {
        "open": "15.55",
        "close": "15.55",
        "high": "15.55",
        "low": "15.52",
        "volume": "670218"
    },
    "2019-12-20 15:58:00": {
        "open": "15.55",
        "close": "15.55",
        "high": "15.55",
        "low": "15.54",
        "volume": "284225"
    }
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

  do {
    let reponseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WorldTradingIntradayData.self, from: resultsJson)

    //get all dates
    let dateArray = reponseData.intraday.keys.map{$0}
    print(dateArray)

    // use the data from `intraday` array like this to get the data
    for date in dateArray {
        let data = reponseData.intraday[date]
        print(data?.open)
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

ask json creator to send the data in below format, you need to have a constant key to parse.
`2019-12-20 15:59:00` time should not be used as a key

```
    "intraday": [
            "dateTime": "2019-12-20 15:59:00",
            "data": {
                "open": "15.55",
                "close": "15.55",
                "high": "15.55",
                "low": "15.52",
                "volume": "670218"
            },
            "dateTime": "2019-12-20 15:59:00",
            "data": {
                "open": "15.55",
                "close": "15.55",
                "high": "15.55",
                "low": "15.52",
                "volume": "670218"
            }
    ]
```

Comment: Requesting the owner of the API to change the format is most often not a way forward and specially for something like this that looks like an API from a 3rd party.

Comment: It is you who have posted an answer, not me

Comment: don't mind, i am just asking for the answer of actual question :)
i am also looking for the answer, how to parse for this scenario.

Comment: If you also are looking for an answer to the above question then why post an answer like this?

Comment: I tried to ask the company to change the format as you recommended, in which they told me " You can do this by adding &formatted=false to your request. "

Comment: Yes Shabbir, it changed the format to 
{"symbol":"SNAP","stock_exchange_short":"NYSE","timezone_name":"America/New_York","intraday":[{"date":"2020-01-08 15:59:00","data":{"open":"16.66","close":"16.67","high":"16.68","low":"16.66","volume":"221296"}}

So now I should be able to get it right

Answer (score -1):

I added &formatted=false to the URL Request, and got a different format, which worked normally and was easy to handle.